# Delete has_one id associate with has_many primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, has-one

### I have 2 models :

```
class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :branding
end
```

---

```
class Branding < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agencies
end
```

when I was destroying any branding, it still keeps its key with the Agency, where I made a field `branding_id`.

I want something which nullifies it when any branding got to destroy in the process.
It automatically updates the agency `branding_id` to `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if `Agency` model has `branding_id` column, it should have `belongs_to` instead of `has_one` and provide `optional: true` option to make `branding` association not required:

```
class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :branding, optional: true
end
```

Second, to do this, you should use `nullify` option, like this:

```
class Branding < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agencies, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Comment: i am using has_one cuz its not necessary if an agency has branding or not...
if I am creating agency without branding in `belongs_to`. it rolls back and doesn't commit in DB as branding_id is necessary due to that. @Marek Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnshulEnbake it's not about if it's necessary or not, if `branding_id` column is in `Agency` model, you have to use `belongs_to`, you can set `optional: true` to this method if it's not necessary (I updated my answer).

Comment: Thanks @Marek Now it working fine but i still can see the id number in console but value is null.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What id do you see? What value is null?

Comment: `Agency.last`
city: nil, url: nil, branding_id: 6 in console, but when i am `Agency.last.branding` it giving null... how it will update its value in Agency table? is it possible to update `branding_id: 6` field to `branding_id:  null` ?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `dependent: :nullify` in `Branding` model?

Answer (score 2):

Rails provides this option, please check below, it will update id to null in agency. for more info check [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

```
class Branding < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agencies, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Comment: This works fine, if i use belongs_to instead of has_one.
but not in has_one case

Comment: @AnshulEnbake Sorry i misunderstood, please check updated answer